# Move Object in direction of mouse

Tags: java

I have a bullet class and an algorithm that will move my bullet to where I pressed, but how would I have the bullet continuing on past the mouse_x and mouse_y when it was clicked?

In My Update method:

```
    float xSpeed = (MoveToX - x) / 9;
    float ySpeed = (MoveToY - y) / 9;

     this.x += xSpeed;
     this.y += ySpeed;
```

And this is when I first create the bullet:

```
Bullet(int Mx, int My){
    c = Color.red;
    MoveToX = Mx;
    MoveToY = My;

    MoveToX += Board.cam.camX;
    MoveToY += Board.cam.camY;
```

Mx is the mouses x when it was clicked. Same with the y.

Edit:
This is my final product: everything works as it should

```
Bullet(int Mx, int My){
    c = Color.red;

    MoveToX = Mx + Board.cam.camX;
    MoveToY = My + Board.cam.camY;

    int speed = 5;
    float distance = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(MoveToX - x, 2) + Math.pow(MoveToY - y, 2));


    amountToMoveX = (((MoveToX - x) / distance) * speed);
    amountToMoveY = (((MoveToY - y) / distance) * speed);

}


public void update(){

    x += amountToMoveX;
    y += amountToMoveY;

}
```

Comment: can u explain a little "how would I have the bullet continuing on past the mouse_x and mouse_y when it was clicked"

Comment: You need to calculate the dX and dY (change in X, change in Y), and tell the bullet to move that much each "step". There are several tutorials available from a basic google search.

Answer (score -1):

The instance variables of your bullet shouldn't be `moveTo_`, but `velocity` and `direction`.
Calculate the `direction` (i.e. the angle) in the constructor, from the bullet position and the target position. `velocity` may also be a static constant, depending on your use case.

If it is an option, I would strongly recommend to *use a physics- or game-engine*. Those kind of problems were already solved a hundred times in those engines. They relieve you from those basic tasks and help you concentrate on your actual problem.